# Scraping HTML table behind paywalled login using rvest

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to access an HTML table behind a paywall for which I have a subscription. Below is a link to a free part of the website for which I'm able to get to and scrape using `rvest`:

```
url <- "https://www.fantasymojo.com/index.php/2019/01/21/2019-best-ball-draft-adp-january/"

table <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_element("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

However, there are parts of the site that are behind a paywalled login (for which I have an account) but can't figure out how to get past that part. Here was my initial attempt:

```
mojo_url <- "https://www.fantasymojo.com/index.php/2020/08/02/2020-ffpc-bestballadp-july/"
url <- jump_to(session, mojo_url)

form <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]

filled_form <- set_values(form,
                          email = "fake@gmail.com",
                          password = "this_is_a_password")
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work and I'm not sure what else to try. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Every site can have it's own way to do authentication. If you need to interactively log in, you'll probably need to use a package like `RSelenium` rather than `rvest` to remotely control a web browser. `rvest` would be great if they had an officially supported API.

Comment: You could try to re-use session cookies from your browser,  for a quick test you can turn cURL commands copied from Chrome dev tools to R / httr snippet. - https://curlconverter.com/r/ . If it happens to work, you can parse httr responses with rvest.